# Object from service result always not valid

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-boot

People is Entity and I think this is valid, but why validator say this not walid? Validator say '*nama*' is null.

```
People orang = peopleService.get(id);
orang.setNama("Nama Baru");
Set<ConstraintViolation<People>> violations = validator.validate(orang);
```

Must like this.

```
People tmp = peopleService.get(id);
People orang = new People();
orang.setId(id);
orang.setNama("Nama Baru");
orang.setJenkel(tmp.getJenkel());
orang.setAlamat(tmp.getAlamat());
Set<ConstraintViolation<People>> violations = validator.validate(orang);
```

What's the different? What's wrong with service result?

EDITED:
This is my People Entity

```
@Entity
public class People implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @NotNull(message = "Jangan biarkan null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Panjang nama minimal 3 karakter")
    private String nama;

    @NotNull(message = "Jangan biarkan null")
    private String jenkel;

    private String alamat;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getJenkel() {
        return jenkel;
    }

    public void setJenkel(String jenkel) {
        this.jenkel = jenkel;
    }

    public String getAlamat() {
        return alamat;
    }

    public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
        this.alamat = alamat;
    }
}
```

And this is peopleService method for get data

```
@Override
public People get(String id)
{
    return peopleRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

Comment: Can your show you `People` Entity? I assume the first example works whereas the second is not?

Comment: My guess is that the People object coming back from the Service is different than the People object that you make in the second code example and that the People object from the service is immutable and therefore you most likely cannot set the name outside of the service.

Comment: Take a look with a debugger how both `orang` variables look like inside at runtime.

Comment: @AlexanderOrlov

`People orang = peopleService.get(id);`

debugger said every member variables value in orang is null :( 
But why when I use orang.getNama() has a value ?

Comment: Well, I change `peopleRepository.getOne(id);` to `peopleRepository.findOne(id);` and it work :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, the orang created using new People() which is different from the first case. But, the problem seems to be in the validation logic. Do you have any custom validator in place which extends Validator ?. If so, Check your validator logic with the People objects or post your People object and Validator logic.

Comment: Yup, the problem in validation. And I did'nt use custom validator.